# Setting up ioc containers in Console

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I would like to use my mvvmcross plugins in a Console app (it is for generating some data that uses shared libraries with my client apps). However, it is not clear to me how I can call Setup. In tests before I was using MvxIoCSupportingTest.

Comment: console app practically has no view, you sure it's the right approach?

Comment: I know, I know. I just need to use some libraries that I usually use for Mvvmcross in a Console. However these are dependent on the IOC provided. I'm making progress with a fake MvxApplication and Setup : MvxConsoleSetup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a console branch of MvvmCross which can be used to develop apps - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Console - and this includes a setup class https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Console/Platform/MvxConsoleSetup.cs. However, realistically, this console platform is not a "real" target for MvvmCross - it has only ever really been used for test/demo. One example console app is in the old TwitterSearch code (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Console) - although sadly that Twitter Search Api is no longer available.

If you don't want views/viewmodels - if you just want *core* IoC and plugin functionality, then this functionality only requires `CrossCore` and you should be able to write your own mini-setup for CrossCore in your console app, similar to the "CrossLight" approach (see N=30 and N=39 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com/)